# list values being rewritten when dictionary values are not reseted inside for-loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, data-manipulation

Something strange is happening to my code that I do not understand. I have the following lines:

```
#informe.py
import csv
from pprint import pprint
def leer_camion(nombre_archivo):
    diccionario = {}
    camion = []

    with open(nombre_archivo, 'rt') as f:
        rows = csv.reader(f)
        headers = next(rows)
        for row in rows:
            diccionario['nombre'] = row[0]
            diccionario['cajones'] = int(row[1])
            diccionario['precio'] = float(row[2]) 
            camion.append(diccionario)
            pprint(camion)
            #diccionario = {}
        return camion


 lista = leer_camion('../Data/camion.csv')
```

My problem is that if I don't reset the dictionary at the end of the `for`, the list is formed as follows:

```
[{'cajones': 100, 'nombre': 'Lima', 'precio': 32.2}]
[{'cajones': 50, 'nombre': 'Naranja', 'precio': 91.1},
 {'cajones': 50, 'nombre': 'Naranja', 'precio': 91.1}]
[{'cajones': 150, 'nombre': 'Caqui', 'precio': 103.44},
 {'cajones': 150, 'nombre': 'Caqui', 'precio': 103.44},
 {'cajones': 150, 'nombre': 'Caqui', 'precio': 103.44}]
...
```

In other words, the dictionary values are rewritten both in the dictionary and in `camion`, if I don't misinterpret. And the final list carries the values from the last column of the csv file. On the other hand, if I uncomment the `dictionary = {}` line, that is, if I reset the dictionary at the end of the loop, the list is correctly formed:

```
[{'cajones': 100, 'nombre': 'Lima', 'precio': 32.2}]
[{'cajones': 100, 'nombre': 'Lima', 'precio': 32.2},
 {'cajones': 50, 'nombre': 'Naranja', 'precio': 91.1}]
[{'cajones': 100, 'nombre': 'Lima', 'precio': 32.2},
 {'cajones': 50, 'nombre': 'Naranja', 'precio': 91.1},
 {'cajones': 150, 'nombre': 'Caqui', 'precio': 103.44}]
...
```

Why does this happen?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you don't reset  it, you're updating the same dictionary each time.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: The normal pattern is to initialize the dictionary at the beginning of the loop body.

Comment: Or just assign the whole dictionary: `diccionario = {'nombre': row[0], 'cajones': int(row[1]), 'precio': float(row[2])}`